# Accessing the value of class variable defined in a class from another class

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the following scenario . I have three classes

CLass A
Class B
Class C

In Class A an object of Class B is created.

In Class B an object of class C is created.

There is a public class variable defined in Class C
which I want to access using an object of Class A in a page.

Is there any way to do this directly ?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Mathew

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property on `A` that references the `C` object:

```
class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
    public int CFoo { get { return B.C.Foo; } set { B.C.Foo = value; } }

    public A() { B = new B(); }
}

class B
{
    public C C { get; set; }
    public B() { C = new C(); }
}

class C
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

From your page, you would do this:

```
 A a = new A();
 // sets A.B.C.Foo
 a.CFoo = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . 
Actually I am looking for a way to do it directly without adding any additional code in any of the classes.
In other words I would to like to know if the framework provides a way to satisfy my requirements.